# Unable to install anything on RHEL Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have created a new Linux (redhat 8.7) VM in Azure, then connected have connected from a Windows Command line using the Windows SSH Client. When I attempt to install anything using either yum or dnf, I receive the following error:

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-7.0

Killed

sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-7.0

Killed
```

Then when I run dnf list I get the following errors:

```
[mjanulaitis@redhat87b /]$ dnf list
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS from RHUI (RPMs)                                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhui-rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rhui-rpms':
  - Curl error (58): Problem with the local SSL certificate for https://rhui-1.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)]
  - Curl error (58): Problem with the local SSL certificate for https://rhui-2.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)]
  - Curl error (58): Problem with the local SSL certificate for https://rhui-3.microsoft.com/pulp/repos/content/dist/rhel8/rhui/8/x86_64/baseos/os/repodata/repomd.xml [could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhui-rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rhui-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "**Killed**" typically indicates that the system terminated the process due to exceeding available memory or other system resources.
In this case, it is possible that the VM does not have enough memory to complete the installation process. You can try increasing the memory of the VM and then try the installation again.

To replicate the scenario, I provisioned [RHEL VM](https://i.imgur.com/CyOrahA.png) with **0.5GiB** RAM and attempted to install the dotnet using the command `sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-7.0 -y`. However, the installation failed.

[image]

Then I incresed the VM size in Azure portal as below.

[image]

After resizing the VM, I retried the installation command, and this time it installed successfully.

[image]

Verfiy the dotnet installation using the below command.

```
dotnet --info
```

[image]